# Background threads in WCF

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf

Is it a good practice to create background thread in a WCF service, hosted with Windows Service?

Something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    private void DoWork()
    {
    ...
    }

    public Service()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I would recommend to just use the **per-call** service model - each request gets its own copy of the service class, the service method in question is called, and then the instance is freed again. That doesn't make it necessary to handle thorny thread-safety issues and stuff like that

Comment: My service is running and listening on network and sending messages to  MVC server via Web API. For per-call service, I need to create a background thread in MVC and duplex communication.. so I prefer to create a background thread in WCF and push messages to MVC. Can you explain, why is it a bad practice?

Comment: What will that background thread do? Why does it need to exist?

Comment: Listening on network, parsing packets and sending them to server

Comment: Why can't you use the usual communication facilities such as WCF calls and REST calls?

Comment: Because I need to send messages to clients asynchronously. I'm using SignalR (Web Sockets like) for pushing messages from web server to browsers.

Comment: I can't say if it's a good practice or not, but I've set up a couple of sites using SignalR that the MVC site either has a web API, web service or listener controller that raises the SignalR context so that other services can communicate.  I've never needed to have the service calls run on their own thread.

Comment: How were you implementing this? Service listening on network, if a specific packet found, service sends it to mvc and mvc pushes it to browser?

Comment: So the background thread *generates* events? Based on what? Time? Btw, it's really hard to help you when we have to tease the information out of you. Please give a lot more detail. This is the last time I will ask you a question trying to help you.

Comment: The background thread is a while(true) loop, which purpose is to catch some specific packets from a network, parse it and send to the web server (via Web API). It should be a regular process, but I wanted to use a WCF service to create an API (Start/StopListening etc.) and call it from the web server. The web server is MVC application, for asynchronous communication between the web server and a client browser, I use SignalR.  After all, what I need, is to display specific packets, parsed, on a client browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a continuous process that pulls data from some source and relays it. This is a good case for a background thread in WCF because your work is not based on incoming calls and it can't be made to be.

Be aware that IIS worker processes can shut down at any point in time for reasons you cannot control. Also, worker processes can overlap when recycling. This means that on the same box two instances of this thread can be running at the same time. The same is true if you want to run this app on multiple machines for HA reasons.

Windows services are more stable but they too must be restartable (for example when deploying or when there is a bug that crashes the process).

Also make sure to catch any errors that happen on that thread. An unhandled exception kills the process with no notification to the developer.

Since you are hosted in a Windows service I see no reason to maintain the thread in the constructor of the `Service` class. Maintain the state outside of WCF. For example in your Windows service class.

Comment: The reason, I create the thread in WCF is, that I'll be able to kill it and create a new one via WCF Interface. For example: public void StopListening() {thread.Abort();} and public void StartListening() {thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork)); tread.start(); }...

Comment: You can do the same thing if you store the thread somewhere else. No need to mess with WCF instancing modes. Also note, that thread.abort is evil. This is not a viable architecture.